# AspNetCoreModuleV2 issue .NET Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

Hoping someone can help out with this issue:

I've deployed my .NET Core 3.0 application on Azure, and even though the it it shows "Publish Succeeded." the application isn't loading (http 500, server error).
The "Diagnose and solve problems" tab in Azure point to the module "AspNetCoreModuleV2" as shown in picture
[Azure - Diagnose and solve problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/htqrg.png)

I've tried:

- Installing the .NET 3.0 Runtime Hosting Bundle as suggested here [aspNetCore 2.2.0 - AspNetCoreModuleV2 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729956/aspnetcore-2-2-0-aspnetcoremodulev2-error)
- Changing the `modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2"` to `modules="AspNetCoreModule"` on the web.config file, but the file reverts back to  its original values once I publish the app.
- Adding `<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>` to the `csproj` but it didn't make a difference so I've deleted that

Here is my current `csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="12.0.3" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.1.0-preview1-final" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In this is what my `web.config` file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\SportsStore.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: 3f1b616a-5c07-4b23-9c86-ec6506dc3fa7-->
```

By the way, the application runs without any issues in the local machine

Any help that can point me in the right direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried publishing as "self-contained" and modifying the web.config, however, nothing worked.

After further research I've found out about the "App Service Editor" tool in Azure. Having a look to the output errors I've realised the issue was to do with the database firewall blocking "my" IP. I had added a rule with my IP previously, however, the IP shown in the error message was different to my actual IP, for some reason. Once the I added another rule on the database with this IP, it worked immediately.

Another strange thing is that the error reported by the "Diagnose and solve problems" tool (AspNetCoreModuleV2) had not much to do with the actual issue.

Thanks everyone for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: Configured the firewall on my Key Vault to allow access from "Selected networks" only, which triggered error "500.30 In-Process Startup Failure" on my .NET Code 3.0 app. Switching Key Vault FW back to All Networks fixed the issue.

Answer (score 10):

Edit your csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModuleV2</AspNetCoreModuleName>
..
```

in this way during `dotnet publish` the `TransformWebConfig` task transforms your `web.config` as following, which works also in Azure WebApp

```
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\assembly.dll" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

In Azure WebApp the `HTTP Error 500.31 - ANCM Failed to Find Native Dependencies` error it seams to be cause by `InProcess` hosting model and module `AspNetCoreModuleV2`

Comment: Thanks for your tip... This line resolved my problem here. I was for 4 day getting 405 cors error anda after all those days, getting this tip to finally resolve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have a check under the `PublishProfiles` folder (inside `Properties`) and ensure you have :

```
<SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
```

> A self-contained application distributes the runtime with the application.

Answer (score 0):

You can try change web.config directly on Azure, so when you deploy application go to the web.config and replace `AspNetCoreModuleV2` to `AspNetCoreModule`. Changing web.config directly will restart application poll, just to understand what is problem.

Please see same article, with possible solutions:

[AspNetCore 3.0 - HTTP Error 500.0 - ANCM In-Process Handler Load Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016776/aspnetcore-3-0-http-error-500-0-ancm-in-process-handler-load-failure/59016777#59016777)

Comment: I thought about doing something like, however, I’m not sure where to find the web.config directly in Azure?

Comment: I think it's not easy to change, otherwise did you try to deploy application as Self-Contained?

Comment: I was trying to avoid deploying as self-contained, as it doesn’t seem to be the best option (based on the documentation at the Microsoft website) but I’m thinking I’ll have to try that...

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me, after spending many hours, I'm using VS 2022. I hope it helps someone else.

In web.config, I changed "inprocess" to "**OutOfProcess**"

```
  <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myappdemo.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="OutOfProcess" />
```